# Why can't I use the increase/decrease horizontal spacing buttons on the layout toolbar in VS 2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-web-developer

I'm trying to learn ASP.NET/C# by following a few simple tutorials (that use Web Developer 2005 in the videos) and I'm trying to drag out a label and a button on the designer canvas and align them using the controls on the layout toolbar but they're disabled. I don't know why.  I'm using absolute positioning to place them. Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the main window is not selected as well as the 2 controls